# Join tables on full text search in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to join two tables based on if a column value in one table has an exact match in a large text column in the other. I guess you could do something like

```
.... JOIN .... ON t1.col ILIKE '%' || t2.col || '%'
```

Is this possible using full text search and tsvector? Using PostgreSQL 13.

Answer (score 1):

I very much overcomplicated this. You can just do

```
.... JOIN .... ON to_tsvector(t1.col) @@ to_tsquery(t2.col)'
```